# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I know this has been asked but the posts prior have not helped me solve this issue.

Full Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://XXX-XXX-XXX.mktoapi.com/soap/mktows/2_5?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "http://XXX-XXX-XXX.mktoapi.com/soap/mktows/2_5?WSDL" in /home1/jameszei/public_html/index.php:84 Stack trace: #0 /home1/jameszei/public_html/index.php(84): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://XXX-XXX-...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home1/jameszei/public_html/index.php on line 84
```

I have to X out some info as this is secure.  But I assure the WSDL is accessible via my browser.

I have updated the php.ini file as follows:

Enabled:

```
file_uploads = On
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
default_socket_timeout = 360
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
```

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $cookieVal = $_COOKIE["_mkto_trk"];
    echo $cookieVal;        

 
 
  $debug = true;
 
  $marketoSoapEndPoint     = "http://XXX-XXX-XXX.mktoapi.com/soap/mktows/2_5";  
  $marketoUserId           = "hidden"; 
  $marketoSecretKey        = "hidden";   
  $marketoNameSpace        = "http://www.marketo.com/mktows/";
 
 
  // Create Signature
  $dtzObj = new DateTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
  $dtObj  = new DateTime('now', $dtzObj);     
  $timeStamp = $dtObj->format(DATE_W3C);
  $encryptString = $timeStamp . $marketoUserId;

  $signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $encryptString, $marketoSecretKey);

 
  // Create SOAP Header
  $attrs = new stdClass();

  $attrs->mktowsUserId = $marketoUserId;

  $attrs->requestSignature = $signature;

  $attrs->requestTimestamp = $timeStamp;

  $authHdr = new SoapHeader($marketoNameSpace, 'AuthenticationHeader', $attrs);

  $options = array("connection_timeout" => 200, "location" => $marketoSoapEndPoint);
  
  if ($debug) {

    $options["trace"] = true;
  }
 
  // Create Request
  $leadKey = array("keyType" => "COOKIE", "keyValue" => $cookieVal);

  $leadKeyParams = array("leadKey" => $leadKey);

  $params = array("paramsGetLead" => $leadKeyParams);


  $client = new SoapClient($marketoSoapEndPoint.'?WSDL', $options);
  echo "good<br/>";  //This never happens since the above line fails
  try {
    $lead = $client->__soapCall('getLead', $params, $options, $authHdr);
    echo "goodTry<br/>"; 
  }
  catch(Exception $ex) {
    var_dump($ex);
  }
 
  if ($debug) {
    print "RAW request:\n" .$client->__getLastRequest() ."\n";
    print "RAW response:\n" .$client->__getLastResponse() ."\n";
  }
  echo $lead;?>
```

I am stumped.  Is this some sort of configuration with my web host?  I am using bluehost to host my page.  The default for php seems to be that they take care of all the installs.  I am using 5.4 single ini.

Do I need to download the .dll files and install them on the server or in my directory on the host?  I seem to have limited access to installing anything on the server, but I can figure that out for sure if I need to.

Thanks for any help.

### EDIT

I decided to just download the xml and save it as a wsdl on my domain.  I now am getting a new error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find
 <definitions> in '/home1/jameszei/public_html
```

This seems really odd since this is the first few lines of the wsdl:

```
<definitions>
<types>
    <schema>
        <!-- ***************************************************************** -->
        <!-- **                       Enumerations                          ** -->
        <!-- ***************************************************************** -->
        <simpleType name="LeadKeyRef">
            <restriction base="string">
                <enumeration value="IDNUM"/>
                <enumeration value="COOKIE"/>
                <enumeration value="EMAIL"/>
                <enumeration value="LEADOWNEREMAIL"/>
                <enumeration value="SFDCACCOUNTID"/>
                <enumeration value="SFDCCONTACTID"/>
                <enumeration value="SFDCLEADID"/>
                <enumeration value="SFDCLEADOWNERID"/>
                <enumeration value="SFDCOPPTYID"/>
            </restriction>
        </simpleType>
        <simpleType name="LeadSyncStatus">
            <restriction base="string">
                <enumeration value="CREATED"/>
                <enumeration value="UPDATED"/>
                <enumeration value="FAILED"/>
            </restriction>
        </simpleType>
```

I am pretty sure  is spelled correct.  I have a feeling this is some sort of other error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

It was my Endpoint - it was not set up with any DNS (grrrrr).  Updated the host file on my machine, used WAMP instead, and now I have complete access.